# Unable to locate package flask_mysqldb

Tags: flask

I'm trying to install flask_mysqldb by using "sudo apt install flask_mysqldb". But I am getting error as "Unable to locate package flask_mysqldb"

Answer (score 0):

This Python package that you can only install from PyPi repository. Check [docs](https://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You need to use `pip` to install it:

```sh
$ pip install flask-mysqldb
```